# Is there anyway to get a list of all cookies residing on a user's machine with Kohana?

Tags: php, session, cookies, kohana

I've been stuck with taking over someone else's existing code. I haven't used Kohana (mainly Laravel and CI) so I don't understand their session and cookie managment well, and googling hasn't been very helpful either.

Basically, I'm tasked with rewriting the current app. I'm trying to see what's currently being used in terms of sessions and cookies, however, the sessions table in Kohana is useless as it provides a session id and a long hashed string that doesn't provide any information, and as for cookies, I only can see a session_id being set on the user's machine, so I'm not sure where the additional data is being stored. Does anyone know if there's a way I can print_r cookie data?

Comment: `print_r($_COOKIE);`? According to the [doc](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Cookie#get) the `Cookie` class uses basic `$_COOKIE` with some salts to "verify" authenticity

Comment: @kingkero if you want to write that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Cookie#get), the `Cookie` class uses regular `$_COOKIE` functionality. So to get raw cookie data, just use

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Since the methods for getting and setting are properly documented, you should be able to retrieve valid cookie information without using `Cookie::get()` but `$_COOKIE[..]` itself.